# OTA Distribute Success in iOS 10 But Failed To Download in Older OS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ota

I have create an OTA link to distribute my in house app, it able to download in iOS10 devices, but it failed to download in iOS9 or older devices, it show Failed to download the app.

My manifest look like below, and minimum deploy version is 8.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>items</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>assets</key>
                        <array>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>software-package</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>https://xxx.company.com/xxx.ipa</string>
                                </dict>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>display-image</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>https://xxx.company.com/image_57.jpg</string>
                                </dict>
                                <dict>
                                        <key>kind</key>
                                        <string>full-size-image</string>
                                        <key>url</key>
                                        <string>https://xxx.company.com/image_512.jpg</string>
                                </dict>
                        </array>
                        <key>metadata</key>
                        <dict>
                                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                <string>com.company.xxx</string>
                                <key>bundle-version</key>
                                <string>0.79</string>
                                <key>kind</key>
                                <string>software</string>
                                <key>title</key>
                                <string>XXX</string>
                        </dict>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Anyone face the same issue and have a solution for this? I have try in few devices, it still the same.

Comment: What is the minimum deployment target of the application?

Comment: minimum I set to 8.2